# Execute multiple mysql query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to execute two mysql query in my C# program but I got the result of the first query only while I want to retrieveall the sql query results.

How to execute the two query and retrieve all results and print them in the console because the reader print the content of the first one only.

```
string wl_query = "select * from `tab1`";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(wl_query, db.connectdb);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string server;
string username;
string password;
string database;
string wl_config_id;
string server_ip;
string server_username;
string user_password;
while (reader.Read())
{
    server = reader["server"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(server);
    username = reader["username"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(username);
    password = reader["password"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(password);
    database = reader["database"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(database);
    wl_config_id = reader["wl_id"].ToString();
    string config_query = "SELECT * FROM `tab_config` where id=" + wl_config_id + ";";
    MySqlCommand config_cmd = new MySqlCommand(config_query, db.connectdb);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        server_ip = reader["server_ip"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(server_ip);
        server_username = reader["server_username"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(server_username);
        user_password = reader["password"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(user_password);
    }
}
```

Comment: obvious approach: one request with a join of both tables

Comment: I would consider using an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), like Entity Framework, instead of writing queries by hand. See [Getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) for some examples. That should make this a non-issue.